# Why socket.emit doesn't working?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have  a variable `id=456643413fc234`.I want to make an emit to the client `socket.broadcast.emit(id,data)`.In client i have the same id with `socket.on(id,function(data){console.log(data})` .Why doesn't works ?

Comment: can you share the server socket code?

Comment: i can't ..i have other sockets and works ...for this one when i change id with 'aaa' is working

Comment: Probably, you aren't using the same id on client and server so the server isn't listening for the right message name.